# How to use template to generate a regular argument list and pass it to run time functions?

Tags: c++, templates

For example, I want to generate a reverse ordered array, but the codes are really redundant.
The constructor is on run-time but the array size is on compile time. However, these codes are very similar.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
using std::array;
array<int32_t, 5> genReverse5() {
  array<int32_t, 5> a{5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
  return a;
}

array<int32_t, 4> genReverse4() {
  array<int32_t, 4> a{ 4, 3, 2, 1};
  return a;
}

array<int32_t, 3> genReverse3() {
  array<int32_t, 3> a{ 3, 2, 1};
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) (since C++14).

```
template <std::size_t... I>
auto genReverse_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  array<int32_t, sizeof...(I)> a{ (sizeof...(I) - I)... }; // decrease progressively
  return a;
}
template<std::size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
auto genReverse()
{
  return genReverse_impl(Indices{});
}
```

then use it as

```
genReverse<5>(); // returns array initialized as {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
genReverse<4>(); // returns array initialized as {4, 3, 2, 1}
genReverse<3>(); // returns array initialized as {3, 2, 1}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TpHOZxkYXbrtKpTX)